# Delete with incorrect parent still succeeds

Tags: elasticsearch, children

In Elasticsearch I have a `_parent` mapping defined for a document type (let's call it `homes`), and some documents indexed. They seem correctly indexed because when I search for parents with children matching some conditions (using `has_child`) the expected results are returned.

The "problem" is that when I issue a delete for a child like...

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/test/homes/1?parent=11'
```

it succeeds even if the parent of the `homes` document with id `1` is not `11`.

Is this the expected behavior?

From my understanding of [Elasticsearch delete API docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete.html) the document would not have to be deleted in this case (but that's not what I'm seeing)...

> The parent parameter can be set, which will basically be the same as
>   setting the `routing` parameter.
>
> ...
>
> Issuing a delete without the correct routing, will cause the document to
>   not be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

the routing (and so the parent) decides, what shard is used. in ES 1.0 the DB knows, that a parent is needed still only uses it to decide, **where to look for**. if the object is there, it will get deleted, but whether the parent is "the real parent" does not matter. what matters is the same hashing result of the parent.

you can perfectly fine create clashing data (same index/type/id on different shards) using parent keys or use fantasy keys - the more shards you have, the more **unlikely** a clash will be, but this does not make it safe. just remeber: *parent* is no foreign key or something strong like we have in the SQL world.

Comment: That would be a plausible explanation if there were a parent (of another child) with id `11`, but this also happens even if there's no such a parent.

Comment: the parent is only needed to store the child on the same shard. ES does not protect you from shooting yourself in the foot with parents (have not yet investigated into 1.0).  if you pass a parent (or even if not) it is used for routing, if the routing ends up by chance on the same shard, then you get your object deleted.  the same is true the other way around - you can index the same object (same id) with different parents in different shards.  The parents relation in ES is very weak and will sooner or later get you.

Comment: I understand that even if the specified parent is not the correct parent, the document will be deleted if it happens to be in the same shard as the incorrect parent. However, the parent `11` does NOT exist (there's no document with that id), so that should return an error and the child should not be deleted, should it? (even if ES parent-child relations are weak)

Comment: parent is only a hash (like routing). it does not reject.  here is a simple example https://gist.github.com/christoph-frick/9893830

Comment: So, you mean that when the parent is specified in a delete request, ES uses the parent only as a hint to know in which shard to find the document to be deleted, but if it's not there (or the specified parent doesn't exist) then the delete is tried against all shards? Or maybe, the parent parameter in a delete operation is simply ignored?

Comment: the routing (and so the parent) decides, what shard is used. in ES 1.0 the DB knows, that a parent is needed still only uses it to decide, where to look for. if the object is there, it will get deleted, but if the parent is "the real parent" does not matter. what matters is the same hashing result of the parent. as you see in my example you can perfectly create clashing data using parent keys. or use fantasy keys - the more shards you have, the more unlikely will be a clash. just remeber: parent is no foreign key or something strong like we have in the SQL world.

Comment: as in my example, there are two shards.  there should be a 50:50 chance to end up on one or the other shard.  It is only a switch on the "frontend" to determine, what "backend" is used.  Then the delete is done there.  If there is an object with that ID, it will get deleted - note the parent no longer matters on the "backend".